# Hide rows if all columns are blank Google Sheets App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

I'm trying to get an automated script that checks if the columns to the right of "D9" are blank and if all of them are, hide the row. My idea was to iterate with a for loop and go row by row and check this, therefore replacing the Row argument in range with 'i' but it seems that for some reason, if I put the A1notation it works but not with 'row' and 'column' arguments. I've just started messing with this a few days ago so I'm certain I'm doing something wrong so if you could point me in the right direction and point me why this doesn't work, that would be great :)

So this works:

> ```
> function SelectLastColumn() {
> var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
> spreadsheet.getRange("D9").activate();
> var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
> spreadsheet.getSelection()
> .getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
> currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
> ```

This doesn't:

> ```
> function SelectLastColumn() { var spreadsheet =
> SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); spreadsheet.getRange(9,4).activate(); var
> currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell(); 
> spreadsheet.getSelection()
> .getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
> currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the reason that above script works and below script doesn't work, how about this answer? In your script, `spreadsheet` of `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` is Spreadsheet as an object. When `getRange()` is used for this situation, it is required to be careful the following points.

- When `getRange()` is used by a1Notation, it can be used for **Spreadsheet** and **Sheet**.
- When `getRange()` is used by row and column, it can be used for only **Sheet**.

From above points, in the case of your script, when your script is modified as follows, your both scripts can be used.

#### From :

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

#### To :

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

#### Reference :

- [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yup. It was my problem. Thanks for the enlightnment :)